# How can I display most of an html page quickly, then load the slow things last?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, taglib

I've got a JSP page like this:

```
<html><body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="firstDisplayStuff">...</div>
    <% out.flush(); %>
    <div id="slowStuff">
        <mytaglib:abc name='SlowBoat'>...</mytaglib>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="floatRightContainer>
    <div id="endingDisplayStuff">...</div>
<div>
</body></html>
```

When it hits the taglib, it takes forever, and that delay can not be avoided.

So using the `out.flush();` I can at least display the `firstDisplayStuff`, but then the user just sits there looking at half a page while the taglib stuff runs.  Only after that's done does the user see `endingDisplayStuff`.

I want `firstDisplayStuff` and `endingDisplayStuff` to both display right away.

But I figured that using jQuery, there would be a way to leave `<div id="slowStuff">` blank, and then load it later.

What would the jQuery code look like to load `<div id="slowStuff">` after both display stuff divs were showing?  Where would I put the code? How would it be invoked?

**EDIT :** Added `<div id=mainContainer>` and `<div id=floatRightContainer>` into the existing example.

Comment: Hmmm, a 50:50 chance of an answer being accepted.

Comment: Yes, @Diodeus, but I ask hard questions, and haven't asked very many.  Some of them still don't have good answers.  But I'll go back and look, just for you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. Just place the last div before the slow one, and use CSS to arrange the divs on the screen as it suits you:

```
<html><body>
<div id="firstDisplayStuff">...</div>
<div id="endingDisplayStuff">...</div>

<% out.flush(); %>
<div id="slowStuff" style="display: none;">
    <mytaglib:abc name='SlowBoat'>...</mytaglib>
</div>
</body></html>
```

You can use a couple lines of code, called from body onload to get the slow div to where it belongs and then to show it.  `$('#slowStuff').insertAfter('#someDiv')` to get it located in the right place, and `$('#slowStuff').show();` to get it to show.

Comment: Using CSS to arrange things is obnoxious. This is really a JS problem.

Comment: CSS is *meant* to arrange things. How can it be obnoxious?

Comment: @FireLizzard - Doing it this way avoids another HTTP request (to load the content with AJAX). I don't see how that's a bad thing.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - I understand avoiding a second HTTP request, but my experience with CSS leads me to shy away from using it to arrange, much less drastically alter the layout from what it would naturally be. I very much like to leave the layout to the HTML and the styling to the CSS. My every attempt to do otherwise has been painful.

Comment: @JBNizet, When I moved the slowStuff div, the taglib content showed-up below the footer.  I guess I need to research how to get CSS to put it back in the containing div where it belongs.

Comment: @JBNizet, I edited your answer...expanded it to include what I ended up doing.  Hopefully it will make it through peer review.  Thanks!!

Comment: That's not really what I thought about, because CSS can be used to display the divs where you want to, without necessary respecting the "natural" order, but I also agree CSS is painful and very hard to get right, and your solution is simple enough, and allows keeping the same CSS as before.

Answer (score 5):

Make a normal Ajax request on DOM ready and fill the div with the rendered HTML:

```
$(function() {
  $("#slowStuff").load(theUrl, etc.)
});
```

See the [`load` docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Make the request to a (JSP, action, controller, whatever) that renders a JSP with the custom tag in it.

Comment: Somewhat related...I'm surprised that part of HTML5 won't be a priority attribute for elements.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I looked at load, but wasn't able to get it working; just loading a random alternate page, it blanked out the entire original page whereas I would have expected to have the random alternate page loaded into the div.  Then there's the "where to put the code" / "how would it be invoked" question. I guess "$(document).ready(function(){...});" is called for, but where?  In body onload? Sorry, I'm learning.

Comment: @Dale It goes in a script tag at the bottom of the html body. Without knowing what you did it's impossible to help diagnose.

Comment: Thanks again Dave.  I opted to go with the CSS solution, but I've got another situation I'll need the ajax solution for.  I'll try the load again there.